# Test Tailwind pruning in React app with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs, tailwind-css

Is there a way to test Tailwind's pruning with Jest, without having to write custom postcss configuration and only implement the default webpack config created by CRA 5 (also implemented [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/an-in-depth-guide-for-create-react-app-5-cra-5-b94b03c233f2)
).

Tailwind seems to be ignoring all classes inside .test.tsx files and isn't including them in the output.

Here are the relevant files:

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx,test.jsx,test.tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./styles/index.scss";
import App from "./Views/App/App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

index.scss

```scss
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

body {
  ...
}
```

App.test.tsx:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("Tailwind Pruning", () => {
  test("Should include style", () => {
    const expected = "rgb(220, 38, 38)";

    render(<span className="text-red-600" data-testid="tailwind-test"></span>);
    const dom = screen.getByTestId("tailwind-test");
    const actual = getComputedStyle(dom).color;

    expect(actual).toBe(expected);
  });

  // tailwind should fail to include the style for this test
  test("Should not include style", () => {
    const expected = "";

    render(<span className={`${"text"}-${"red"}-${600}`} data-testid="tailwind-test"></span>);
    const dom = screen.getByTestId("tailwind-test");
    const actual = getComputedStyle(dom).color;

    expect(actual).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
};

// *.test.ts or *.test.js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import "./styles.css";

test("renders a div with the correct class", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <div data-testid="test" className="bg-blue-500"></div>
  );
  const div = getByTestId("test");

  expect(div).toHaveClass("bg-blue-500");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question was about testing tailwind's pruning functionality. I want to check that only the classnames that are included in the render are included in the final css.

Comment: I don't think there's way to test pure functionality of the tailwind css style.

Comment: It's probably doable if you emulate the whole build process and include that single jsx part that would be in the `render`, but that's too complicated, I just wanted to add a short test that fails if for whatever reason there is a problem with tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem two weeks ago, and got to solve it by doing something like this:

- `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        // all mock names
        '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/tailwindcss', // try to do this, it works without error
    },
}
```

And if you want to check if it works, try to `debug()` anywhere inside your code test cases then you can get the class names that you have used inside your code (that is what you're testing), *also class names can be converted for styling like in my case, I used `hsl()` it gives me in `rgb()` in console debugging*.

I hope this helps!